# Adjusting the long-run expected value of a variable in a VAR model through the constant term

Tags: regression, time-series, vector-autoregression, intercept

I am currently trying to fit a VAR model to, amongst other variables, inflation data and want the long run limit of inflation to be 2%, i.e. the ECB target. Say my VAR looks like this:
$$
X_t = c + \Pi X_{t-1} + \epsilon_t,
$$

and assume the VAR is stable. Several papers mention one can set long run target by adjusting the constant term $c$. However none of the papers I read give an explanation on how. Is it possible to modify the constant term so that my inflation variable moves to 2%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X_t$ is a stationary process, it will tend to its expected value $\mu_X=\mathbb{E}(X_t)$ (a vector). This would be the long-run limit of $X_t$ if not for the $\varepsilon_t$ that keeps kicking $X_t$ away from it.

Take expected value of both sides of the equation,
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}(X_t) &= \mathbb{E}(c+\Pi X_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t) \\
&=\mathbb{E}(c)+\Pi \mathbb{E}(X_{t-1})+\mathbb{E}(\varepsilon_t) \\
&=c+\Pi \mathbb{E}(X_{t-1})+0.
\end{aligned}
Since $\mathbb{E}(X_t)=\mathbb{E}(X_{t-1})$, the last equation becomes
$$
\mu_X = c+\Pi \mu_X
$$
which yields 
$$
(I-\Pi)\mu_X = c
$$
where $I$ is an identity matrix of a suitable dimension. Then
$$
\mu_X = (I-\Pi)^{-1} c.
$$
If you take $\Pi$ as given and want a particular component of $X$, $X_i$, to have a particular expected value, tweak the $i$th element of $c$, $c_i$, to achieve the desired result. E.g. if for a given $c_i$ you have $E(X_i)$ estimated at 5 but you want 2, set the new $c_i'$ as $\frac{2}{5} c_i$.

Comment: Thanks again, this was exactly the answer I was looking for!